# How to mark a function callable from host and device?

Tags: cuda

I have bunch of common functions like `swap`, `min`, `max` etc. How to mark them so I could call them both from the host and from the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `__host__` `__device__` before the function declaration, like:

```
__host__ __device__ int min(int A, int B) {return (A<B)?A:B;}
```

This is documented in the C programming guide [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-type-qualifiers).

Comment: Thank you, I missed the fact I can join them.